# Test Language Modeling Tensorflow tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to LSTM and Tensorflow and I tried the tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent with srouce code in :
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb
the script
    python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=simple-examples/data/
worked well and the model was saved successfully
Now I don't know how to test the saved model, is ther some tutorial for this.
I know that I can restore the model but how can I test the restored model?